# About Atom Personalization

Tags: css, atom-editor

I started using Atom today. It's great, but I have a couple of issues:

- Syntax Themes: I installed some syntax themes, but I found one cannot modify editor font colors, just style and size (from the main settings pane). Is there any workaround?
- Markdown Preview: I was unable to find out how to change preview style.
  I mean, markdown is rendered with arial fonts and a white background.
  Is there any way to change this default behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to customize both in your user stylesheet. On Mac OS X, you can open this using *Atom > Open Your Stylesheet*, which will open the `~/.atom/styles.less` file.

For the syntax themes: You can customize the colors in your `styles.less` file, simply take a look at the theme's source LESS file and then override the settings in your custom stylesheet. More details and an example can be found [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/changing-syntax-highlighting-colours/12534).

Markdown Preview: The [Markdown Preview package](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview) has an example on how to do that in your own `styles.less` file:

```
.markdown-preview.markdown-preview {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Take a look at the Markdown LESS files to see some of the styles you could override:

- Default style: https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/blob/master/styles%2Fmarkdown-preview-default.less
- GitHub style: https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview/blob/master/styles%2Fmarkdown-preview-github.less

Comment: Their stylesheet looks similar to the default one: https://github.com/Galadirith/markdown-preview-plus/blob/master/styles/markdown-preview.less

Comment: Thanks again.. May I ask how you found that page?

Comment: Google for `atom markdown-preview-plus`, then open browse to its GitHub repo, open the `styles` folder. That's where all of the Atom packages have their stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

The `markdown-preview-plus` documentation now gives a different approach to styling the preview (even from the "snippet" provided in their README"):

> To target Markdown-Preview-Plus rendering in general, you can do something like this in your stylesheet:
>
> ```css
> html[data-markdown-preview-plus-context] body {
>  /* styles that affect mpp preview */
> }
> ```

Full details (especially on further "contexts") in [the MPP docs](https://github.com/atom-community/markdown-preview-plus/blob/master/docs/styling-preview.md).